# How to force my Android new application installation?

Tags: android, google-play

How to force my Android new application installation when ever user comes to application?

Basically I am releasing new set of features. I would like to force user to update user to this new version?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force the user to upgrade the app.

You can build functionality into the app which, for example, checks a server of yours for the latest version, and disallows any use of the app if the user is behind. (This of course does not guarantee an upgrade!) But this approach is *very* ingratiating to the user and is not at all recommended. Your best bet is to incentivize your customers by providing bug fixes and awesome new features.